# Adding an html link to each image shown in the link. How to set each?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM adoption;");

if($result->num_rows !=NULL){
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $AAnimalName = $rows['AAnimalName'];
        $Abreed = $rows['Abreed'];
        $Asex = $rows['Asex'];
        $Acolor = $rows['Acolor'];
        $image = $rows ['image'];
        $image_location = "admin/function/upload/".$image; ?>
        <div class="container-custom1">
        <?php
        if(file_exists($image_location )) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image_location.'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
        }
    else {
    echo '<img src="admin/images/admin_logo.png" width="248" height="190" class="age1" title>'; } ?>

        <?php echo "<i><h1 class='junction'><a style='cursor:pointer' class='junction'>".$AAnimalName."</a></h1></i>"."<br>".$Asex." / ".$Abreed."<br>".$Acolor."<br>"?></div> 

<?php

    } }   
?>
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hA5k.jpg see picture first. How to add link that leads to further information on each of the image inside my `div=container-custom`

Comment: *"How to add link"* - This is HTML 101 stuff.

Comment: Still on PHP i think, inside the php loop. Sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: I learned HTML way before I learned PHP, which is something any web developer should know. Don't take this the wrong way, but you should know how basic HTML works. `<a href="xxx">LINK</a>`

Comment: I know how but it's inside a loop and must have id for each. I don't do it, i think my html will get longer and longer. I just want to shorten

Answer (score 0):

Add an href to your existing anchor tag. If you already have routing setup for more details pages just output that route in the href or dynamically build one e.g.

```
#stored route in db
$url = $rows['url'];
...href="{$url}"...
```

or

```
#using ids from db
$id = $rows['id'];
...href="/path/to/details/{$id}"...
```

Comment: So you mean to say i have to store id or any in the field that will be used for linking the html for each?

Comment: Is this inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, in the anchor tag that is in the loop. I'm just offering suggestions on linking I don't know what your file/logic structure is like for your sub pages. You can use and ID, you can use a slug, whatever.